# Export report with Developer Console - "Store listing visitors"

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-play-developer-api, developer-console

I know that Google Play Developer Console has multiple exportable csv files that contain info about your apps daily downloads, uninstalls and so on (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en).

But in none of these files I could find the Store listing visitors, does anyone know how to export this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK! there's a report that lets you see how many users have visited your listing and how many have installed, but that report does not let you directly export / download it.

[image]